# SqlDelight not generating SQL Query String for SQL Statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite, stored-procedures, sqldelight

In the example in the [SqlDelight documentation](https://github.com/square/sqldelight#join-projections), the `HockeyPlayerModel` generated by SqlDelight from a `HockeyPlayer.sq` file is implemented in an abstract class `public abstract class HockeyPlayer implements HockeyPlayerModel`

In this class, the string `SELECT_ALL_INFO` is passed in as the query to `db.rawQuery(SELECT_ALL_INFO, new String[0])`. The string `SELECT_ALL_INFO` was generated by the `select_all_info` statement inside `HockeyPlayer.sq`. However, in my situation, my statements are not generating strings. Why is this?

My statement

```
names_for_groups:
SELECT DISTINCT name, exercise_set_group FROM exercise_set JOIN exercises
USING (exercise_id) WHERE workout_FK = ? ORDER BY exercise_set_group ASC ;
```

My implementation of the `ExerciseSetModel` being generated by SqlDelight

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class DbExerciseSet implements ExerciseSetModel, DbItem {
    public static final Factory<DbExerciseSet> FACTORY = new Factory<>(AutoValue_DbExerciseSet::new);
    public static final RowMapper<DbExerciseSet> MAPPER = FACTORY.select_allMapper();

    public static final RowMapper<NamesForGroups> NAMES_FOR_GROUPS_MAPPER =
            FACTORY.names_for_groupsMapper(AutoValue_DbExerciseSet_NamesForGroups::new);

    public List<NamesForGroups> namesForGroups(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        List<NamesForGroups> namesForGroupsList= new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(NAMES_FOR_GROUPS, new String[0]);
            while (cursor.moveToNext() && NAMES_FOR_GROUPS_MAPPER.map(cursor) != null) {
                //NamesForGroups namesForGroups = NAMES_FOR_GROUPS_MAPPER.map(cursor);
                namesForGroupsList.add(NAMES_FOR_GROUPS_MAPPER.map(cursor));
            }

        return namesForGroupsList;
    }

    @AutoValue
    public abstract static class NamesForGroups implements Names_for_groupsModel {}

    @AutoValue
    public abstract static class Exercises implements ExerciseModel {}
}
```

To be clear, the variable reference NAMES_FOR_GROUPS is not found in the line `db.rawQuery(NAMES_FOR_GROUPS, new String[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation needs to be updated, I'll do that. We no longer generate Strings in SQLDelight 0.6.+ instead there is a method on the factory which returns a `SQLDelightStatement` that is used to query:

```
public List<NamesForGroups> namesForGroups(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    List<NamesForGroups> namesForGroupsList= new ArrayList<>();
    SQLDelightStatement query = FACTORY.name_for_groups();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query.statement, query.args);
        while (cursor.moveToNext() && NAMES_FOR_GROUPS_MAPPER.map(cursor) != null) {
            //NamesForGroups namesForGroups = NAMES_FOR_GROUPS_MAPPER.map(cursor);
            namesForGroupsList.add(NAMES_FOR_GROUPS_MAPPER.map(cursor));
        }

    return namesForGroupsList;
}
```

Comment: full pull request with documentation changes: https://github.com/square/sqldelight/pull/628

Comment: much appreciated; I was wracking my brain over this for quite awhile